# How to keep HTML form field that is conditional hidden with javasript hidden after page reload?

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

I have an html form in which I conditionally hide a field with javascript if an option is selected in the dropdown. The javascript condition works fine but when the page is reloaded the condition is lost even though the right option is still selected.

Steps to recreate:

1. I have a js code to store user input in session storage because my users might sometimes have to go to another page and come back to the form later.
2. I have a js code to conditionally hide a field named `price_input_div` when the third option is selected in select field.

The problem:

When I click on the third option, the `price_input_div` field is hidden but when the page is reloaded, the field appears again even though the third option is still selected (the third option is still selected because I am saving the value in session storage).

After the page is reloaded, when I select another option then select the third option again, the `price_input_div` field becomes hidden once again.

The HTML form:

```
<p class="form-row form-row-wide">
<label for="select_price_option">Price option<span class="required"> *</span></label>
<select name="select_price_option" id="select_price_option" />
<option disabled selected value> Please select one</option>
<option>Total fee</option>
<option>Starting fee</option>
<option>I need more information</option>
</select>
</p>

<p class="form-row form-row-wide" id="price_input_div">
<label for="quote_price_input">Enter your price</label>
<input type="text" name="quote_price_input" id="quote_price_input" class="input-text"/>
</p>

<p class="form-row form-row-wide">
<label for="message_to_customer">Enter your message<span class="required"> *</span></label>
<textarea name="message_to_customer" id="message_to_customer" minlength="30" class="input-text"></textarea>
</p>
```

The Js code to save and get field value in session storage:

```
// Save custom checkout fields to session storage
(function ($) {
    // Run on page load
window.onload = function() {
    var quote_price_input = sessionStorage.getItem("quote_price_input");
    var message_to_customer = sessionStorage.getItem("message_to_customer");
    var select_price_option = sessionStorage.getItem("select_price_option");

    if(quote_price_input !== null) {
    document.getElementById('quote_price_input').value = quote_price_input;
      } else
    document.getElementById('quote_price_input').value = "";

    if(select_price_option !== null) {
        var sel = document.getElementById('select_price_option');
        var opts = sel.options;
        for (var opt, j = 0; opt = opts[j]; j++) {
            console.log(opt.innerHTML);
            if (opt.innerHTML == select_price_option) {
              sel.selectedIndex = j;
              break;
            }
        }
      }

    if(message_to_customer !== null) {
    document.getElementById('message_to_customer').innerHTML = message_to_customer;
      } else
    document.getElementById('message_to_customer').innerHTML = "";
};

// Before refreshing the page, save the form data to sessionStorage
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    var quote_price_input = document.getElementById('quote_price_input');
    var message_to_customer = document.getElementById('message_to_customer');
    var select_price_option = document.getElementById('select_price_option');

    if(quote_price_input !== null) {
        sessionStorage.setItem('quote_price_input', $('#quote_price_input').val());
    }

    if(select_price_option !== null) {
        sessionStorage.setItem('select_price_option', $('#select_price_option').val());
    }

    if(message_to_customer !== null) {
        sessionStorage.setItem('message_to_customer', $('#message_to_customer').val());
    }
};
})(jQuery);
```

The js code to conditionally hide `price_input_div` field:

```
(function ($) {
$("#select_price_option").change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == "I need more information") {
    $('#price_input_div').hide();
  } else {
    $('#price_input_div').show();
  }
});
$("#select_price_option").trigger("change");
})(jQuery);
```

I want the `price_input_div` field to remain hidden even after page reload since `I need more information` is still selected.

I tried the below code as well but no luck:

```
// Conditionally show price
(function ($) {
window.onload = function() {
$("#select_price_option").change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == "I need more information") {
    $('#price_input_div').hide();
  } else {
    $('#price_input_div').show();
  }
});
$("#select_price_option").trigger("change");
}})(jQuery);
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
// Conditionally show price
(function ($) {
  window.onload = function() {

  if ($("#select_price_option").val() == "I need more information") {
   $('#price_input_div').hide();
  }

$("#select_price_option").change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == "I need more information") {
    $('#price_input_div').hide();
  } else {
    $('#price_input_div').show();
  }
 });
 }})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Hello, I tried your code but the condition did not work at all. Kindly review it. Thanks

Comment: Please provide the snapshot or code changes you did.

Comment: I only changed this text "I need more info to give a price" to "I need more information". I did not change anything in the code.

Comment: Please share the form HTML and js changes you did so that I can check from my side. And after the selection when you reload the page it is not hiding the field?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. Do you mean the changes I made to your code? I did not make any changes to your code. I simply copied it and replaced it with my code posted above.

Comment: The code above isn't working because your Select Options don't have any values assigned, so what's the jQuery actually comparing.  If none of the options have a value of "I need more information" then none of them will ever match that condition.

So, in your form:
<option value="I need more information.">I need more information.</option>

And then use the jQuery that Bhupen provided.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment, your select options don't have any values, but your condition in jQuery checks their value...

```
<select name="select_price_option" id="select_price_option" />
<option disabled selected> Please select one</option>
<option value="Total fee">Total fee</option>
<option value="Starting fee">Starting fee</option>
<option value="I need more information">I need more information</option>
</select>
```

Then, when your jQuery runs the conditional check, like @Bhupen recommended, this condition will work:

`if ($("#select_price_option").val() == "I need more information") {`

As will the one lower down:

`if ($(this).val() == "I need more information") {`